# Question wrongfully closed and locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-questions

> This post is regarding the following question:
>   **[Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)**

Was this question wrongfully closed and locked?

- I believe this is a good, on-topic question befitting the site with a great answer.
- There *are* fundamental, factual differences between hashing and encryption algorithms
- Not much discussion was generated about it.
- It doesn't have that many answers.
- The first answer is one of the most informative pieces of text on the subject on the internet.
- It wasn't in risk of being deleted, highly upvoted, no close votes.

Can we get it reopen and unlocked please?

Comment: Incidentally; (Madara already knows this), but for others' information, I am the one who closed/locked that question, and I encouraged this Meta post to inquire about it.

Comment: Closing and locking just prevents more answers and comments. It can stand as a reference - I highly doubt it's on its way to deletion.

Comment: @KateGregory It's quite possible I'm remembering this wrong or something, but does Locking not prevent regular users from deleting it in the first place? That was one of the reasons I locked it in addition to closing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber good point - I am over 10K on SO and see no edit, flag, or delete links under the question - only share.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: For deleting it, it must be closed first (and it wasn't close to being closed), and with the score it had, at least 7 different people needed to vote to delete it to delete it. This question was not about to be deleted.

Comment: @KateGregory We can't even flag locked questions. This is deep freeze indeed, reducing chances of deletion to 0. As I see it, such lock is enforced on questions at risk of being deleted by the users themselves.

Comment: @AndrewBarber would you mind tell me why you locked ... this post if perfectly suited for so and very helpful .... its not like the books suggestion question and answer are awesome ...

Comment: @AndrewBarber please dont stop us to share love on good post .... please do not lock good post ..

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have unlocked and reopened it, after the arguments you and Anna made.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not a crypto expert by any means, but I believe there are distinct applications of hashes vs encryption algorithms, so this isn't a comparison question the same way "should I use ruby or python for my boring CRUD app" is.

The "will likely solicit debate" argument breaks down quickly when we're looking at a 2-year-old question that just kind of didn't. :) If anything, a "too broad" closure would make a bit more sense to me because of the bit about the mathematical background.

Either way, the question wasn't at all controversial and produced on-topic, substantiated content. I don't think think either locking the question or closing it was necessary. A couple answers were more recent and rather subpar, but that's what voting is for.

Comment: I see your point there. Coupled with what Madara and I talked about, I've unlocked and reopened it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sounds great to me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Madara that there is no reason that I can see to lock that post. Not only prevents it the answerers from getting reps for their great answers, but it also sends the wrong signal with the lock message:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**,...

Emphasize not mine. If the issue with the question is the fact it asks for opinions I would much rather see the question rephrased to fix this (which is something we cannot do now anymore) instead of mod locking the thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but it might be closed because it asks opinions and thus "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". Nevertheless, I agree that it's a good question with great answers.

Comment: Just because the word "opinions" appears in the question, doesn't mean it will solicit debate, arguments, polling or extended discussion. (Funny fact, it didn't do any of those things)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That's why the word "likely" is used.

Comment: @user2448027 You misundertood him. He was saying that it was not a question that belonged to that category, even if it used the word opinion. He didn't meant that the question belonged to that category, but luckily it didn't generate arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This question is asking for the difference between two loosely-related concepts. What's the difference between a raven and a writing desk? So that could justify a view that the question is coming out of the blue and needs some motivation as to why the asker has trouble distinguishing between a raven and a writing desk. However, there is a widespread confusion between hashing and encryption due to historical password hashing implementations being called [`crypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) (and their documentation even today often speaks of “encryption”), even though password hashing is neither encryption nor hashing. So I disagree with the judgement that it is *non-constructive*.

However, other close reasons may apply. A large part of the question is *off-topic*. ”When to use hashes vs encryption“ can be answered in a programming context, but the second part “What makes a hash or encryption algorithm different (from a theoretical/mathematical level) i.e. what makes hashes irreversible (without aid of a rainbow tree)” is not related to programming. Stack Overflow has traditionally been tolerant of off-topic questions which were about computer science, mathematics, system administration, intellectual property law, etc., but nowadays SO focuses on programming. Many of these topics have dedicated Stack Exchange sites; [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) applies in the case at hand. So closing as off-topic and putting a historical lock on the question is reasonable.

Furthermore, the question is a mediocre one to start with, because it is far too broad. What the asker needs here isn't a Stack Exchange answer, but a whole book about cryptography. Or at least Wikipedia, as hinted by the accepted answer. So closing as *not a real question — too broad* makes sense.

There is one good answer ([the accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393) — but note that it is not as good as the content you can find spread over more reasonable-sized chunks on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)), which is a reason to preserve the thread. I disagree with historical locks in principle (I would prefer to move the content off-site), but the way the lock has been applied is perfectly consistent with the historical lock policy.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not a great one under current standards.  It is broad and open-ended, and if asked today it would be a better fit on the [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) sites.

I don't think there's any need to delete the question at this point, given that it already has some detailed answers. However, if it were asked today as a new question, I would be recommending that it be migrated, that it be narrowed down, and that the asker do a little bit of research on those sites first.  Moreover, I'm not sure there is much value at this point in adding new answers to this question.  Therefore, I don't perceive any great need to re-open or unprotect the question.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good question with good answers, but sometimes questions get locked to prevent debate and long discussions. If a Q & A starts to become a discussion, it should be moved to a chat room asap.

Comment: However, in the text that explains locking, it says _"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed"_. So it's obviously not considered a good question.

Comment: That's not what a historical lock is for. There's a lock for that. ALSO, look at the question, it hadn't generated much discussion.